# how to identify no of states?

Tags: state-machines

If a sequential circuit will produce output as high if both present and previous inputs represent even number with present input being LSB. How many states are required to analyze this? how to identify and choose a parameter as state?

Comment: well,do an approach.

Comment: You may have paraphrased the problem statement incorrectly, leaving out crucial information. As stated, if the "present input" is the LSB, that's all the information you need: If it's "1", the number is odd; if it's "0", the number is even.

Comment: Huh? What? ----

Comment: Well I'm really hoping that aparna lets us know if "will produce output as high if both present and previous inputs represent even number" means two evens in a row or something else Dave.

Comment: aparna, I hope you have seen my answer and it has helped you.  I worry that you question will be deleted.  It turns out Dave Tweed and Olin Lathrop have been here, along with a few others, for a long time. This gives them the power to be rude and delete questions when it is too hard for them to understand.  I would have thought after my response to DT below he might have apologized.  I would have if I down voted someone out of ignorance.  But then, I don't have to go online and berate people.  I wonder about people that do that.  What must be going on in their lives.

Comment: @owg60 "Bad" questions don't get deleted, they get closed. This is to give people opportunities to improve or clarify their question. I believe that this question, *at best*, is unclear. It can be very difficult to succinctly ask a question especially if you don't know what phrases may be ambiguous and/or have a less-than-perfect grasp of English. It's also easy to completely misread the tone and intent of responses, as written word is one of the hardest methods for conveying tone.

Comment: @W5VO  It may not be perfect English, but I think the intent is clear to any engineer that has experience designing state machines.  The tone is not hard to discern for a comment that starts with "Another terrible answer".  It appears on this site a bad question is one that can't be understood by a few curmudgeons.  I've been coming to this site for a little under a month.  What I see is a few people chasing ways new users.  For the people that these questions are hard for, why not just let it go.  Does it really make these guys feel like great engineers by belittling students. Shame on Them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a a mealy maching, you need two states  Either the previous LSB was zero or not.  If it was 0 and you get another 0 output 1 and set to previous number even again.  If it was 0 and you get a 1 output 0 and set to previous number odd.  Even and odd only depend on the LSB.

Ok, there is a little question on what to do with the first bit.  I'm assuming that if it is even the machine will not output a one since there was not a previous even number.  This can be taken care of by initializing the machine to the odd state.  Doing that, the state machine looks like this;

[image: Two Even Detect Mealy Machine]

I've assigned the even state 0 and the odd state 1.  You should see this would be easy to do with a D flip-flop.  The rays on this diagram have labels in the form input/output.  You see that if it is in the even state, another even will stay in the even and output a 1.  If it is in the even state and the next input is a 1 it will not output a zero and go to the odd state.  The input is going to have to be syncronized for this to work without glitches.

Perhaps I'm missunderstanding the question.  Here is what I thought you asked for;

[image: Two Even in a Row Mealy Machine]

Here is the output showing that two or more evens in a row produce a one output;

[image: Two even simulation output]

If I understood the question correctly, the number of states is two.

Comment: does each condition represent a state in mealy machine?

Comment: I've updated the answer with the state diagram.  The states of the machine are odd if the previous lsb was one and even if the previous lsb was 0.

Comment: Another terrible answer. I'm not sure what your state machine is supposed to do, but it doesn't have anything to do with determining whether a 2-bit number is odd or even.

Comment: Dave, where does it say the number is  2 bits?  It only says a series of numbers are even or odd and we are looking at the least significant bit.  So if the LSB is 0 it is even.  If the LSB is 1 it is odd.  That's true for 2 bits.  It is true of any number of bits.  The problem is to output a one if there are two evens in a row.  That is what the present one and the previous one means.  That's what the state diagram in the answer shows.  Not only is it a good answer, it is one right answer.

Comment: @owg60: thank you. you answer helped me.

Comment: @DaveTweed: present bit is LSB n previous bit is next higher bit i.e for 2 bits previous bit is MSB.

Comment: So my original interpretation *was* correct!

Comment: Yes Dave your interpretation was correct.  There were always the two possibilities.  But as any knowledgeable engineer can see whether it is a series of parallel numbers or growing number in the form of 2x+0 or 2x+1 doesn't change the problem.  They both require the same number of states.  And both cases come down to is there two evens in a row, which we have not forgotten you could not understand.  And you thought that lack of understanding gave you permission to violate StackExchange's premise of being nice.  Did you think this vindicated you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out how many states you need your system to have.  For example if you want to decode a 2-bit number into a one hot signal at each cycle

```
00 => 0001; 
01 => 0010; 
10 => 0100; 
11 => 1000
```

you would need four states to represent the 2-bit input number (2^2).
Four states can be realized with two registers in binary (00 01 10 11).

If you wanted to decode a 3-bit number

```
000 => 00000001; 
001 => 00000010; 
010 => 00000100; 
011 => 00001000; 
100 => 00010000; 
101 => 00100000; 
110 => 01000000; 
111 => 10000000
```

then you would need 8 states to represent this number (2^3). This can be done with 3 bits in binary.

For any number N of binary bits, you can represent up to 2^N distinct states.

The examples are pretty arbitrary but, so is your question :P

Comment: This is a good way to answer an overly broad question ;-)

Comment: @jbord39: does even or odd  depend on last two bits in binary?

Comment: @jbord39: what is the least possible no of states I can have ?

Comment: This is actually a terrible answer. It doesn't address the actual question, which refers to data being presented serially, and regardless, decoding is a combinatorial process that doesn't require any states at all. This will be thoroughly confusing to the OP.

Comment: @DaveTweed: I said decode once per clock cycle (as in register the input bits), and I never said the data comes in serially (you assumed that, and it is not true in my example).  I just picked a very short combinational path (registers -> logic -> out; all just single cycle).  Sorry if this doesn't make sense to you but it is true!  Try generating a one hot 1000 0100 0010 0001 mapping as I said from a single input register bit, you cannot (you need two bits).  I would think you would realize this though.